# Running project that has a .so file dependent on a newer version of GLIBC than I have installed on my system

Tags: linux, glibc

I am attempting to run the software stored in this repository: https://github.com/uwnlp/EasySRL.

I am a user on a cluster machine and as such have no root access.

I compile the above project with ant and then attempt to run in on my system and get the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/deeptaggerlibdeeptagger.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /tmp/deeptaggerlibdeeptagger.so)
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1822)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
at edu.uw.deeptagger.DeepTagger.loadLib(DeepTagger.java:57)
at edu.uw.deeptagger.DeepTagger.loadFromJar(DeepTagger.java:35)
at edu.uw.deeptagger.DeepTagger.<clinit>(DeepTagger.java:25)
at edu.uw.easysrl.syntax.tagger.TaggerLSTM.makeDeepTagger(Unknown Source)
at edu.uw.easysrl.syntax.tagger.TaggerLSTM.<init>(Unknown Source)
at edu.uw.easysrl.syntax.tagger.Tagger.make(Unknown Source)
at edu.uw.easysrl.syntax.parser.ParserBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
at edu.uw.easysrl.main.EasySRL.makePipelineParser(Unknown Source)
at edu.uw.easysrl.main.EasySRL.main(Unknown Source)
```

I think this is because /tmp/deeptaggerlibdeeptagger.so was compiled against a newer version of GLIBC than we have installed on our cluster.

```
-bash-4.1$ strings /lib/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC_2.1

GLIBC_2.1
GLIBC_2.1.1
GLIBC_2.1.2
GLIBC_2.1.3
GLIBC_2.10
GLIBC_2.11
GLIBC_2.12
```

I have tried the following:

1. Install a new version of GLIBC locally by doing the following:

   ```
      mkdir ~/glibc_install; cd ~/glibc_install

      wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.14.tar.gz

      tar zxvf glibc-2.14.tar.gz

      cd glibc-2.14

      mkdir build

      cd build

      ../configure --prefix=/home/opt/glibc-2.14

      make -j4

      make install
   ```

and then export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/opt/glibc-2.14/lib. When I run the program now, nothing happens.

2. I have also tried using [patchelf](https://nixos.org/patchelf.html)

   ```
   ./patchelf --set-interpreter /path/to/newglibc/ld-linux.so.2 --set-rpath /path/to/newglibc/ /tmp/deeptaggerlibdeeptagger.so
   ```

Which gives the following error: cannot find section .interp

I thought that perhaps rebuilding the .so file on the cluster with native version of glibc would be the best option, but I don't think I have access to the source files.

I know there are quite a few questions of a similar nature to this on SE SU etc. I have tried as many of the proposed solutions as possible (a lot of them seem to be many years old now).

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Tried to make an [AppImage](https://appimage.org/)?